# Can't output anything using cygwin 1.7 gcc under windows

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I just installed cygwin 1.7, and wrote a simple Hello world in `test.c`

but when I complie, nothing happens, even no error messages

`gcc-4 -o test.exe test.c`

[image]

And there's nothing generated under my folder.

I have included `C:\cygwin;C:\cygwin\bin` in my PATH

Did I miss something?

**EDIT:**

for more information, I installed Qt4, tortoiseHg, and mingw before.
Now I had removed mingw. but still got Qt4 and tortoiseHg, is this a problem?

Comment: Check the output folder permissions, is all I can suggest.  I've used cygwin to build entire libraries and haven't had the problem you're seeing.

Comment: @JulieinAustin The output folder's permission is ok, I'm thinking maybe I had miss some lib pathes to the PATH environment var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this from the Cygwin Terminal, not `cmd.exe`:

```
$ cd `cygpath -u "$USERPROFILE"`/Desktop/UT
$ gcc -o foo foo.c
$ ls -l foo
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 yourlogin None 19618 May 10 05:15 foo*
```

If that works, there's some bogus remnant lying around.

You'll find that the Cygwin experience is generally better running under Bash, in a MinTTY terminal anyway. `cmd.exe` doesn't understand Cygwinisms, and is a DOS throwback besides.

Note that you don't need to say `gcc-4` to get GCC 4.x. `gcc` is GCC 4.x on Cygwin, and has been for quite some time now.

Also note that you don't need to include `.exe` in the GCC `-o` flag, because Cygwin GCC knows to add that already.

Comment: The bug is fixed, it's because the polution of my PATH. Thanks

Comment: That's what I was thinking when I vaguely wrote about remnants. Some bit of MinGW left laying around, I guess?

Comment: Not only mingw, I have qt4 installed, which has it's own mingw complier. I'm now using cygwin under it's terminal only, and don't have any idea of the PATH polution.